How can we measure bias in content recomendation systems?
Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this (maybe I should ask a statistics forum?).
I want to know whether there has been any good work for econometrics people about measuring bias in content recomendation algorithms. I'm interested in measuring bias in a black-box way (i.e, using the inputs and outputs of the algorthim, not inspecting the algorithm itself), and I'm interested in the high-level conceptual question of how to address confounding. How can we experimentally distinguish between the case where a platform reccomends content from the category C at rate of R and the users of the platform demand C content at a rate of R from the case where the platform recomends content from the category C at a rate of R and the users of the platform demand C content at a rate of R' and the difference between R and R' is due to downweighting/upweighting. What could we measure to distinguish these cases? I feel like some smart econometrics people must have thoughts about this issue, but I'm not an econ/stats person so I'm hoping to avoid having to search through the literature myself.
Any thoughts, econ folks?
